# Linear combinations of rows with matching row attributes in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to subtract corresponding rows by months in a datatable
Here is the example table

```
   monthly_date sector_order Retail Sales Trend Sales
1:   2014-12-01            1     42123.87    42279.64
2:   2015-11-01            1     44181.69    43620.22
3:   2015-12-01            1     43207.97    43605.21
4:   2014-12-01           30     14972.60    15025.74
5:   2015-11-01           30     15969.98    15685.36
6:   2015-12-01           30     15478.42    15675.09
```

Is there an elegant way to give me a 3 row table with the rows with
sector_order==30 subtracted from the rows with sector_order==1
I can obviously brute force it with two data frames.  Is there a more general data.table way?

Comment: You mean like ``data[ , .(diff(`Retail Sales`), diff(`Trend Sales`)), by = monthly_date]``?

Comment: I will try it shortly

Comment: I want to subtract sector 30 from sector 1 for each month

Comment: then add this to `i`: `order(-sector_order)`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option

```
library(data.table) 
data[, .(RetailSales = RetailSales[1L] - RetailSales[.N], 
          TrendSales = TrendSales[1L] - TrendSales[.N]), by = monthly_date]

#   monthly_date RetailSales TrendSales
#1:   2014-12-01    27151.27   27253.90
#2:   2015-11-01    28211.71   27934.86
#3:   2015-12-01    27729.55   27930.12
```

or as @MichaelChirico suggested a more elegant solution

```
data[order(-sector_order),.(RetailSales = diff(RetailSales),
                            TrendSales  = diff(TrendSales)), by = monthly_date]
```

Or as @Frank suggested

```
data[order(-sector_order), 
  .SD[2]-.SD[1] 
  # lapply(.SD, diff) # also works here
, by=monthly_date, .SDcols=c("RetailSales","TrendSales")]
```

**data**

```
data = setDT(structure(list(monthly_date = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L), .Label = c("2014-12-01", "2015-11-01", "2015-12-01"), class = "factor"), 
    sector_order = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 30L, 30L, 30L), RetailSales = c(42123.87, 
    44181.69, 43207.97, 14972.6, 15969.98, 15478.42), TrendSales = c(42279.64, 
    43620.22, 43605.21, 15025.74, 15685.36, 15675.09), grp = c(1L, 
    2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L)), .Names = c("monthly_date", "sector_order", 
"RetailSales", "TrendSales", "grp"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L)))
```